# Algorithm Analysis - theoretical approach

Tags: algorithm, theory, analysis

I'm taking a course related to Algorithm Analysis. The thing is the course is more focused on the theoretical part. By that I mean we don't actually take real algorithms and study them, we just take random recursions or very basic examples. I've searched this site and I also did a general search on google for a book with more examples of algorithm analysis.
For example: The course just introduced a little of recursion functions analysis with methods like: iteration, master theorem, substitution, recursion tree. At the seminars or lab we have been introduced to some problems, but with any calculating like thing you just can't learn it by watching just 2 or 3 examples and then doing those over and over again. To truly understand them you must do a lot of examples.
Does anybody know a book with a lot on examples, or a book focused on problems?

Comment: @djechlin and others why have you flagged my post? I try to use a grammatical English and I've asked a programming related question.

Comment: Why was it closed? Because [you shouldn't ask for book recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113684/206447).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you prof. Tim Roughgarden's [Algorithms: Design and Analysis: Part I](https://class.coursera.org/algo/lecture/preview), from Stanford. This are online classes, but you can watch the videos without enrolling to the course. I remember that  [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) was explained perfectly and there were a lot of good examples. There is also part II of this course, if you are interested.

Classical book about algorithms (a bible) is [Introduction To Algorithms](http://books.google.pl/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&redir_esc=y) by Cormen et al.

Comment: Just went a little through the book in your second paragraph. While it does have problems at the end of every chapter, they don't have solutions to check myself. It's still useful to see different approaches of explaining the concepts.
I do have a course related to studying algorithms themselves in the second semester. Some programming guru thought it would be a good idea to split them in half and study them separately -_-'